Pimcore View Editor not saving a custom root folder
I'm currently setting up Pimcore and installed the perspective editor to create quicker custom views and perspectives. But i experiencing problems when it comes to saving an individual root folder. All other settings we're saved without any issue.
Did I forget something. I entered the path in the same way as in the available examples.
Pimcore Version: v11.2.3
Root folder setting in view editor
Installing the bundle package again. But it isn't working anyway.
